# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application, access-denied

I am developing C# windows based application. I am getting

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   Access is denied

in my installed application.

```
2011-01-05 12:41:42,916, ERROR, RINXUI.main, System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

I get this error only when I install application. When I try to debug my application from Visual studio, there is no exception.

I have installed application using IzPack installer utility and its installed on desktop (for testing purpose).

Anyone knows why this exception is occuring only in installed version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` from stack trace - are you trying to launch any process from your application. If yes then you need to see if the a/c under which your application is running has sufficient privileges to read/write the location where executable is stored.

Comment: I have admin privilages on my system but then also this exception is occuring. When I run application from Visual studio, it works fine but when create installer and run app after installation then only this error comes.

Comment: @Shekhar, if you copy app files (instead of say using installer) and then run - does it work? Also, if this is Vista/Win7/2008 server machine, then check if UAC (User Account Control) getting in the way by disabling it.

Comment: I solved the problem. Problem was in the path. After installation, path of exe which my application invokes was not getting copied properly. Thats why this error was coming.